# Selecting value returning as random text rather than integer

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using PHP and mysqli to connect to a MySQL database and I am using this command to SELECT:

```
SELECT value AS txt FROM `variables21` WHERE name = 'db_gold::$uuid'
```

And where $gold in the following code should return `500` which is what is in phpMyAdmin, it is returning `@@`.

Code:

```
$query = "SELECT value AS txt FROM `variables21` WHERE name = 'db_gold::$uuid'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($conn), E_USER_ERROR);
if($result) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $gold = $row['txt'];
    }
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: You haven't shown the code you use to get the results

Comment: This is the code I'm using @SamiKuhmonen: http://hastebin.com/wekifiguqo.pl I can get strings from my mysql database fine but integers just don't seem to work.

Comment: @Pang $gold is returning @@ and on phpMyAdmin it is 500.

Comment: Try putting `var_dump($row)` in the while loop to see what's in `$row`.